# Add the Brave's homepage to Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, brave-browser

I installed [Brave](https://brave.com) for fun, and I am impressed by Brave's homepage which i want to add in to my Firefox's homepage with some changes.

[image]

As you see above the homepage of Brave has time on right-up corner which I want it to be in center and the background images should be custom.

I was not able to even find the homepage's HTML and JavaScript so that I can just change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Preferences -> Home, you can use a custom URL and point to a local file where you store the homepage you want :

[image]

Comment: Thanks man but i have a last doubt how can i get homepage filesof brave browser??

Comment: You can save it with `File -> Save Page As...`, but you cannot reuse it easily on Firefox because it uses Javascript files specific to Chrome.

Comment: well by using `File -> Save Page As...` u only get html what about css and js

Comment: CSS is embedded in the HTML file. JavaScript is embedded in the Brave browser, you can access it with URL such as `chrome://resources/js/util.js`, but this won't work ,as is, in Firefox.

Comment: thanks i will just go through the code and check out if can do it or not